# Discount rules between cronjobs at 01:00 and 02:00

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, catalog-price-rules, crontab

By default, Magento has 2 cronjobs that run at 01:00 and 02:00.

```
catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all 0 2 * * *
catalogrule_apply_all   0 1 * * *
```

Does this mean that between 01:00 and 02:00 all discount prices are invalidated and it takes another hour until all prices are reindexed?

I have a client complaining that discount prices are often not working around midnight (midnights only).

It seems obvious these are related. Would it be safe to move these two closer to each other? Like 10 minutes in between:

```
catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all 10 1 * * *
catalogrule_apply_all 0 1 * * *
```

And, while I'm at it, I assume I can move those to 04:00 as well, right?

So, final question.. should I change these crons to:

```
catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all 10 4 * * *
catalogrule_apply_all 0 4 * * *
```

Or will I run into problems?